# Is it faster to search more nested objects or more documents in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm considering the following document structures for my mongodb database. The first model would lead to a lot more documents, but the second model would have a lot more 'event' objects within each 'events' array. There are thousands of 'event' objects in each 'events' array by the way.

I need to be able to filter the objects in the 'events' array, by bookmaker, sport, market, exchange, league, and events. The most common query though is with no filters. Which model is best, will having more documents significantly slow down a request to get the event objects?

```
{
    bookmaker: 'Bet365',
    sport: 'Football',
    market: 'Match Result'
    data: [
        {
            exchange: 'Smarkets',
            data: [
                {
                    league: 'English Premier League',
                    events: [...],
                    last_update: '84792394832'
                },
                {
                    league: 'English Championship',
                    events: [...],
                    last_update: '84792394832'
                },
                ...
            ]
        }
        ... more exchanges
    ]
}
```

and then this one...

```
{
    bookmaker: 'Bet365',
    data: [
        {
            sport: 'Tennis',
            events: [...],
            last_update: '84792394832'
        },
        {
            league: 'Football',
            events: [...],
            last_update: '84792394832'
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

For the second model, the market, exchange and league are in each event object within the events array. I'm assuming trying to filter by market, exchange or league would be a lot slower now, as the query would have to check every object in the 'events' array, rather than just being able to write off the whole document almost straight away. In contrast though, is the second a lot faster for fetching the 'event' object in the 'events' array?

**EDIT:**
I need to store about 100,000 of the 'event' objects like the one below, if I use the first document model above then I won't need to store, the market, exchange or league. With the second model above, I would have about 30 documents each with 3000-4000 of these 'event' objects embedded in the 'events' properties and with the first model, I would have about 500 documents, each with around 200 embedded documents in them. I think the first model would be better for me, but I want to know if this model would be a lot slower for when I want to pull every 'event' object out of the database.
Here's the 'event' object...

```
{
    event_id: 'fl23rtkb5kh1hren213h',
    date: '2308323922',
    event: 'Man United vs Liverpool',
    bet: 'Man United',
    market: 'Match Result',
    league: 'English Premier League',
    bookmaker: 'Bet365',
    odds1: 3.3,
    exchange: 'Smarkets',
    odds2: 3.4,
    availability: 132.11,
    rating: 98.11,
    snr_rating: 62.15
}
```

Comment: "Which model is best" will lead to opinions

Comment: The **data model** is affected by factors like amount of data, size, the important operations (the application), and other factors like available hardware. It is quite normal to create models, sample data, and try out some queries (the important ones) and verify the effectiveness. Array fields in MongoDB documents is an important feature. It can be used effectively with proper understanding of the data, its usage and available tools (array operators, etc). One of the important aspect of the array fields is it needs be bounded, irrespective of the size. Arrays can be indexed too.

Comment: I've made an edit to my question, I mostly just need to know if a query takes much longer if you increase the number of documents, but reduce the number of embedded objects?